# Responsive modal window

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am working on Bootstrap 4 modal window with responsive layout. For that I am using:
[Bootstrap 4 Modal Resizable](http://gijgo.com/Dialog/demos/bootstrap-4-modal-resizable)

Everything is working fine so far except when the window is resized its content is not responsive. Here is my markup code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="dialog.open()">Reopen</button>
<div id="dialog" class="card">
     <div class="card-block">
       <form class="row" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">name</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control"
                       style="height:30px;width:200px;" id="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control"
                       style="height:30px;width:250px;" id="description" />
            </div>
        </div> 
       </form>           
     </div>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45tbox4f/69/)

What I am noticing is that it takes a very narrow window for columns to respond. Any idea how to make it better responding to resizing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45tbox4f/75/)

If you remove `class="row"` and add `class="form-inline"` 
& remove `class="col-6"` from the children `divs`, it should be responsive.